# Some questions concerning the generators of cyclic groups

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity, primitive-roots

Let $g(p)$ be the least positive [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) of the prime $p$, the primitive roots being the generators of the [cyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$. These are the values for the first prime numbers:

$$g(3) = 2$$

$$g(5) = 2$$

$$g(7) = 3$$

$$g(11) = 2$$

$$g(13) = 2$$

$$g(17) = 3$$

$$g(19) = 2$$

$$g(23) = 5$$

$$g(29) = 2$$

$$g(31) = 3$$

$$g(37) = 2$$

$$g(41) = 6$$

I've [learned](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2996618/1792) that it's hard to calculate $g(p)$ for arbitrary $p$.

### Main questions

> (1) Is there a known connection between $g(p)$ and
> some other number theoretic functions?
> <sub>E.g. $g(p)=$ some number theoretic function $f$ of the number [$\phi(p-1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)</sub>
>
> (2) Is there a known connection between the property $g(p)=2$ and
> some other number theoretic properties?
> <sub>E.g. $g(p)=2$ iff the number [$\phi(p-1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) has some number theoretic property $P$</sub>

**Side questions**

> (3) What's the asymptotic probability that $g(p) = 2$?
>
> (4) Are there values $g(p)$ cannot take? 
> <sub>What about $g(p) = 4$ and higher powers of $2$? What about $g(p) = 9$? See [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C5%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C6&sort=&language=german&go=Suche).</sub>
>
> (5) How hard is $g(p)$ exactly?
> <sub>Is it possibly [NP hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness)?</sub>

Comment: Not a complete answer but something worth mentioning is Artin's primitive root conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots 
it gives a conjectural answer to (3)

Comment: Ah, and it's also an answer to (4)!